# Rotate face in image

Tags: image-processing, opencv, rotation, image-rotation

I have a problem, when i take a photo with my tablet, i use opencv for detecting a face and recognition a face. So i would try to rotate the face in order to have for example the eyes and mounth in the same position for example all with the same horizontal angle.
Can you suggest me some OpenCv functions or some useful links for do this?
Thanks in advance.
Marco

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the opencv remapping tutorial might help
http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/remap/remap.html#remap

---

Full answer:

Use this to locate the eyes [cascade_classifier](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier)
now when you have a point for each eye - build the line equation and use simple trigonometry to find the angle. when you have the angle - use the remap to rotate or even better use this [warp_affine](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html#warp-affine)

Comment: Hi Jan, what i want is to detect eyes in a image, find the angle respect an horizontal line and rotate the image for having all the face in the same pose.

Comment: use this to locate the eyes http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier   now when you have a point for each eye - build the line equation and use simple trigonometry to find the angle. when you have the angle - use the remap to rotate or even better use this http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html#warp-affine

Comment: No problem, If it helped, please consider rating the answer and/or accepting it by clicking on the V sign under the answer rank and making it green.